# Easy way to make a loop in shell

Tags: shell, loops

I would like to print an array as

```
001 002 003 .. 010 021 022 .. 030 041 042 .. 050
```

I had written the following script to do that. This is working well, but it is printing like

001 021 041 002 022 042 ....

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in {1..10}; do
while [ $i -le 50 ]; do
if [[ $i -le 9 ]];then n=00$i;else n=0$i;fi
echo $n
i=$(( i + 20 ))
done
done
```

I am looking for a easy way so that it will print like

```
001 002 003 .. 010 021 022 .. 030 041 042 .. 050
```

Comment: More elegant insted of `if [[ $i -le 9 ]];then n=00$i;else n=0$i;fi` would be `n=$( printf '%03' $i )`

Comment: Just to make sure, the array members are {1-10,21-30,41-50}?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are using Linux (since `seq` is often not installed in something like FreeBSD).

You can use `seq` with `-f` option.

first `seq` prints `001 .. 010`

second `seq` prints `021 .. 030`

and the last `seq` prints `041 .. 050`

```
for i in {0..2}
  do seq -f '%03g' $((i*20+1)) $((i*20+10))
done
```

Comment: Ah, `-f` is better than my answer where scaling could be a problem. +1

Comment: Arithmetic expansion with `$(( ... ))` is not a `bash`-ism.

Answer (score 1):

A `for`-loop in a shell needs to operate on a static set, but you change `$i` in your loop.

Instead, use a `while`-loop:

```
i=1
while [ $i -le 50 ]; do
    printf "%03d " $i

    if [ $( expr $i % 10 ) -eq 0 ]; then
        i=$(( i + 11 ))
    else
        i=$(( i + 1 ))
    fi
done
echo
```

Or, with `bash` or `ksh`:

```
i=1
while (( i <= 50 )); do
    printf "%03d " $i

    if (( (i % 10) == 0 )); then
        (( i += 11 ))
    else
        (( ++i ))
    fi
done
echo
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [numrange](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/):

```
numrange /001..010,021..030,041..050/
```

Output (space delimited):

> 001 002 003 004 005 006 007 008 009 010 021 022 023 024 025 026 027
>   028 029 030 041 042 043 044 045 046 047 048 049 050

For linefeed delimiters add the `-N` option (30 line output not shown):

```
numrange -N /001..010,021..030,041..050/
```

Answer (score 1):

**bash**:

```
echo {001..010} {021..030} {041..050}
```

Output:

> 001 002 003 004 005 006 007 008 009 010 021 022 023 024 025 026 027 028 029 030 041 042 043 044 045 046 047 048 049 050